# how to validate Nim should contain 10 digits?

Tags: java

I have made that what is entered must be int and must be positive and now I want to add validation so that the number entered must contain 10 digits

```
try {
       nim = Integer.parseInt(txtNIM.getText());
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        throw new numberException();
    }if (nim < 0) {
         throw new PositiveException();
    }
```

Comment: Hi @RizkyDhani - since you've already required >=0, can't you just check nim >= 1000000000?

Comment: For the exception: Exception names usually display what is wrong. A "PositiveException" would indicate a positive (thing) is encountered where there should be zero or negative. Better have that Exception be called "NegativeNumberException" or something alike, if you can help it.

Answer (score 0):

```java
try {
       int count = 0;
       nim = Integer.parseInt(txtNIM.getText());
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        throw new numberException();
    }if (nim < 0) {
         throw new PositiveException();
    }
    int nim1 = nim;
    for (nim1 != 0; nim1 /= 10, ++count) {
    }
    if (count < 10) {
         throw new PositiveException();
    }
```

`count` variable will count the total digits of the number

Comment: @RizkyDhani you have to initialize count integer

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
   nimStr=txtNIM.getText();
   if(nimStr.length() !=10){
       throw new numberLengthNotTenException(); //this is a custom exception that  
                                                 //needs to be created outside by 
                                                 //yourself
   // or else you can just print something to console directly and not throw an error
  }
  else{
   nim = Integer.parseInt(nimStr);
  }
   


} 
catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    throw new numberException();
}
catch(numberLengthNotTenException e){ //add this if you want to throw custom exception
   System.out.println(e);
}
if (nim < 0) {
     throw new PositiveException();
}
```

[how to create custom exception](https://www.baeldung.com/java-new-custom-exception)

Answer (score 0):

Utilize the [String#matches()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_matches.htm) method with a [Regular Expression](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html) (RegEx) however, you should keep in mind that a 10 digit number can potentially exceed the Integer MAX_VALUE of **2147483647** and **will** throw an exception, therefore your Integer variable should be of a Long Integer data type and the numerical string be parsed as such with `Long.parseLong()`:

```
String nimStrg = txtNIM.getText();
long nim;

/* The string numerical value must be no more
   and no less than ten digits and can not 
   start with zero (0).                */
if (!nimStrg.matches("^[1-9][0-9]{9}$")) {
    System.out.println("Invalid Numerical Value!");
    // exit mechanism here if it's required...
}
else {
    nim = Long.parseLong(nimStrg);
}
```